# Setting a property of a property in a struct?

Tags: c#, properties, struct, member

I created a struct, that has another struct as a property. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
MyColor.RGBColor.R = 255;
```

MyColor and RGBColor being the structs I created. This doesn't work, I set a whole new value to RGBColor, but that's not straightforward and there has to be an easier way. Currently, I have to do this:

```
MyColor.RGBColor = new RGBColor(255, MyColor.RGColor.G ...)
```

I'm pretty sure if I stopped encapsualting the private properties in public properties, and just make them public in the first place, I won't have this problem... but I always read that this is a bad thing to do, so how can I go about this? Thanks

EDIT:

This is how I implement the properties currently:

```
private rgbcolor _RGBColor;
public rgbcolor RGBColor {
  get {
    return _RGBColor;
  }
  set {
    _RGBColor = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code including your structs?

Comment: @NickKarnik ok, I added the way the properties are set up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. By accessing the property `RGBColor`, you invoke its getter method, which returns the struct's instance *by value*. Even though you would then assign (which, in fact, even doesn't compile) a value into `R`, the struct itself **is not stored** back into the `RGBColor` property — even if it had a setter. This is just how value types behave.

If you can, just avoid using structs. In the world of classes with automatic references and properties with getter/setter methods they tend to be very counter-intuitive. Trying to represent small classes (in terms of data size) as structs is [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Note: What you call a “private property” is **not** a property. It's a member field.

Comment: I could do that, but I'm trying to avoid making my colors a reference type

Comment: @leaf68 That's premature optimization. See my updated answer. Just don't do it unless you really *have* to.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to make classes act a bit more like value types where "=" copies it instead of making a reference?

Comment: No. Why? Create your own `Clone` method that will take the specifics of your program into account.

Answer (score 0):

---

You should look at conventions for class names vs. variable names. You seem to have it somewhat backwards in your implementation.

---

Here's what I think you're trying to do:

```
private rgbcolor _RGBColor = new rgbcolor();
public rgbcolor RGBColor {
  get {
    return _RGBColor;
  }
}
```

Once that's in place, you should be able to do something like (assuming there's a property R on rgbcolor)

```
MyColor.RGBColor.R = 255;
```

This will work because the instance for MyColor.RGBColor will exist when the RGBColor property is accessed.

Comment: Providing `rgbcolor` is a struct, this doesn't even compile…

Answer (score 0):

When you use value types (structs) you should keep in mind that passing them in methods as parameters or returning from methods (also in some other cases) always cause making a copy of that object. Properties are just the methods after compilation. So your code in fact equal:

```
var copy = MyColor.RGBColor; // you get a copy now
copy.R = 255; // and now you change a copy, not the original object's value
```

C# compiller understand that this is an error and don't compile your desired variant. Because of this it's strongly recomended to create **imutable** structs. In your case it's better to use classes.